# "for true {}" occurring "missing return at end of function"

Tags: go

Look at the below two code snippets:
**code1:**

```
func getIntJ1() (j int32) {
    for {
        j = 20
        return
    }
}
```

**code2:**

```
func getIntJ2() (j int32) {
    for true {
        j = 20
        return
    }
}
```

Playground : https://play.golang.org/p/ZnwjZDksZhu

I think they should print the same value `20` in the console, but they can't do what I want.
The `code1` could print value `20` in the console, but the `code2` occurs compile error: **`missing return at end of function`**.

All of them have an `infinite loop` in the function, why they display in different result?

Comment: Why do you give me so many down-votes, is it valueless?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To prevent functions from running off the end without returning their return value, Go has a concept of a [*terminating statement*](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Terminating_statements). Terminating statements are certain types of statements where it can easily be shown that execution will not continue past that statement. A function with result parameters must end in a terminating statement.

A `for` with no `break` and no loop condition counts as a terminating statement, but a `for` with a loop condition doesn't count, even if that loop condition is always true. (The rules could be expanded to count a `for` with `true` as its condition as a terminating statement, but adding too many cases makes the definition more confusing than useful.) Your second `getIntJ` definition has no terminating statement.

Answer (score 2):

As instructed, insert the return.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println(getIntJ1())
    fmt.Println(getIntJ2())
}

func getIntJ1() (j int32) {
    for {
        j = 20
        if j == 21 {
            continue
        }
        return
    }
}

func getIntJ2() (j int32) {
    for true {
        j = 20
        if j == 21 {
            continue
        }
        return
    }
    return
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/QbYQ6NkOMpQ

Output:

```
20
20
```

For `getIntJ1`, `for {}`, the `return` is never needed.  For `getIntJ2`, `for condition {}`, the `return` may be needed. The compiler could be smarter when `condition` is `true`

It's more idiomatic to write `for {}` rather than `for true {}`.

Comment: What are the differences between `for {}` and `for true {}`?

Comment: @ShuaiJunlan: They are the same.